# Understanding definition of Django's model class

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-class

If we create a new model as follows,

```
from django.db import models   

class Book(models.Model): 
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and run the database migrations, then I understand that
the corresponding table is created with column names and field types, and I understand that we can do the following:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Book
>>> book = Book(title="Matilda", author="Roald Dahl")
>>> book.save()
>>> print book.title
Matilda
```

However I am struggling a little to understand the python code
in the class definition, just in terms of how I understood classes to work, and was hoping someone could help
my understanding with the following questions:

1. In the definition of the class Book, title seems to be a
   class attribute. This class attribute is set to an instance of
   the CharField class? In which case when we create an instance of
   the Book class, if we do not pass in an argument, would title
   be set to this same instance of CharField?
2. When we pass in title='Matilda' on creating this instance of Book, is this then overriding the attribute title?
3. How do we know that Book takes in title as an argument?

I hope these make sense. Thank you for any help.
Lizzie

Comment: Well, you are sub-classing from `django.db.models.Model`, which is a complex class (see source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L404). It is aimed to make user experience easy to define your models and how to use them. If you want to dive deep into the internals, by all means you can.

Comment: "*In which case when we create an instance of the Book class, if we do not pass in an argument, would title be set to this same instance of CharField?*". No, Django makes use of a meta class, and overrides `__get__` and `__set__` python descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a model class in Django, consider that class the data-table, each individual instance of that class the table rows, and the attributes(e.g: title) of each table the columns.

> In the definition of the class Book, title seems to be a class attribute. This class attribute is set to an instance of the CharField class? In which case when we create an instance of the Book class, if we do not pass in an argument, would title be set to this same instance of CharField?

‘title’ would be a field in the data table and the ‘CharField’ would be a type of field; each field is assigned a type by you using classes like ‘CharField’, ‘TexrField’, etc. You don’t necessarily have to pass in a value for ‘title’ (or any field) if you give a default value when describing the type, example:

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=‘unknown’)
```

> When we pass in title='Matilda' on creating this instance of Book, is this then overriding the attribute title?

You are giving it a value of ‘Matilda’ as it doesn’t have a title until you give it one (or provide a default when making the field).

> How do we know that Book takes in title as an argument?

Because you wrote it in the model class; it really depends on how you’re going to input the data really. If you’re making some kind of page that takes input from a user, display the ‘title’ field in a form and make it mandatory. You can make fields optional when you assign the type of field, like

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=true, blank=true)
```